# boolean argument not passing correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm new to jQuery and im just trying to pass a boolean to a function.Ive tried various amendments but still not working ?

I'm expecting the alert to be fired

```
isTrue(true);

function isTrue(boolean isNot){
    if(isNot){
      alert('true');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider reading a basic JavaScript tutorial. Also, keep your browser's developer console open so you can see potential errors.

Comment: Additionally, Java and JavaScript are not the same thing.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

JavaScript (not Java) has no type indicators, just variable names. Remove `boolean`

```
function isTrue(isNot){
    if(isNot){
      alert('true');
    }
}
```

Comment: This may not work as expected. For instance, if the `isNot` argument is the string `false`, the `if(isNot){` statement will evaluate to true, since the string `false` is truthy. More information here: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: @JohnWasham The OP did say *he's passing a boolean*.

Comment: My comment was for other users who may happen upon this answer and not realize what they thought was a boolean was actually a string "true" or "false".

Comment: Better explain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332839/set-a-default-value-for-a-boolean-parameter-in-a-javascript-function