# Set a default value for a boolean parameter in a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have used `typeof foo !== 'undefined'` to test optional parameters in javascript functions, but if I want this value to be `true` or `false` every time, what is the simplest or quickest or most thorough way? It seems like it could be simpler than this:

```
function logBool(x) {
    x = typeof x !== 'undefined' && x ? true : false;
    console.log(x);
}

var a, b = false, c = true;
logBool(a); // false
logBool(b); // false
logBool(c); // true
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could skip the ternary, and evaluate the "not not x", e.g. `!!x`.

If x is undefined, `!x` is true, so `!!x` becomes false again. If x is true, `!x` is false so `!!x` is true.

```
function logBool(x) {
    x = !!x;
    console.log(x);
}

var a, b = false, c = true;
logBool(a); // false
logBool(b); // false
logBool(c); // true
```

Comment: someone please protect this answer :)